# Sqlite database crashes to main screen

Tags: java, android, sqlite

yesterday i had a similar problem but one of the guy helped me to solve the problem. The problem is when i launch the app and click a button to get to another form and it crashes back to the main screen. can it be that i want to have multiple databases and thats the problem? Debuged the program and pasted the result below, if somebody has some free time i would apreciate the time :)

Code for sqlite

```
    package com.example.laivumusis;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.example.laivumusis.KlausimuContracts.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class KlausimynoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Klausimynas.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public KlausimynoDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;

        final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                KlausimuLentele._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
                KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER" +
                ")";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
        fillKlausimuLentele();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private void fillKlausimuLentele() {
        Klausimai q1 = new Klausimai("A is correct", "A", "B", "C", 1);
        addQuestion(q1);
        Klausimai q2 = new Klausimai("B is correct", "A", "B", "C", 2);
        addQuestion(q2);
        Klausimai q3 = new Klausimai("C is correct", "A", "B", "C", 3);
        addQuestion(q3);
        Klausimai q4 = new Klausimai("A is correct again", "A", "B", "C", 1);
        addQuestion(q4);
        Klausimai q5 = new Klausimai("B is correct agian", "A", "B", "C", 2);
        addQuestion(q5);
    }

    private void addQuestion(Klausimai klausimai) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION, klausimai.getKlausimas());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION1, klausimai.getPasirinkimas1());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION2, klausimai.getPasirinkimas2());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION3, klausimai.getPasirinkimas3());
        cv.put(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_ANSWER_NR, klausimai.getAtsakymoNr());
        db.insert(KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    }

    public List<Klausimai> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Klausimai> klausimuSarasas = new ArrayList<>();
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + KlausimuLentele.TABLE_NAME, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Klausimai klausimai = new Klausimai();
                klausimai.setKlausimas(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
                klausimai.setPasirinkimas1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION1)));
                klausimai.setPasirinkimas2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION2)));
                klausimai.setPasirinkimas3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_OPTION3)));
                klausimai.setAtsakymoNr(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KlausimuLentele.COLLUMN_ANSWER_NR)));
                klausimuSarasas.add(klausimai);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
        return klausimuSarasas;

    }
}
```

DEBUG error code

```
  E/SQLiteLog: (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY in "CREATE TABLE klausimyno_klausimai ( _idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, klausimai TEXT, pasirinkimas1 TEXT, pasirinkimas2 TEXT, pasirinkimas3 TEXT,
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

Comment: Column declaration `_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` defines a column named `_idINTEGER` to be a `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTOINCREMENT`, but doesn't have a declared data type. The error says the column must be declared `INTEGER` and you didn't. Why is the error confusing you?

Comment: Sry im pretty new to java and android studio i still don't fully understand the language :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space in between:

```
_idINTEGER

KlausimuLentele._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
```

Like:

```
_id INTEGER

 KlausimuLentele._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
```

So:

```
"INTEGER -> " INTEGER //space
```

Comment: Thx, worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Welcome! Please accept the answer so that others may know the solution for it.